# Want to add Skype, Whatsapp, Call,Email to joomla menu bar

Tags: joomla3.0

This is the link to my site http://safehandindia.com/orgch/

I have code for all four icons. If i go to create a joomla menu item with icon i am confused as to where to place the respective code for it. Like for skype icon button I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Call">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "dropdown",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call",
          "participants": ["name"],
          "imageSize": 24
        });
      </script>
    </div>
```

Where i should lace this code so as to get a icon beside 'Search' menu item in my page. So when any one clicks on it it goes to skype app. If i get a solution for this rest I can solve

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom html module in which you will paste your code. (switch the text editor to html)

Then publish this module on all pages in the same position as your search module. The order of modules will be important as this will place your icons before or after the search field.

If necessary, you can then style the content of the newly created module.

Comment: The search here is not a seperate modle it is a menu item icon in the main menu bar. Now if I go to create a new html module as you said, and if i give it the same module position as the menu, it will push the menu right? I want to to be as menu item..just like how I have email and call icons. You can see here. http://www.safehandindia.com/orgch/. I tried creating a menu item with external url and placed  skype:live:skype.user123?chat as external link for the menu item. It says "save not permitted'

Comment: I have seen. You can style the new module for it ton integrate. If you want to change the order of the icons, you could as well integrate the search icon in the custom html or create a second menu for the search and publish the custom html module between the two menus.

Comment: Ok will give a try like as you said. Thanks Wiglaf